# How can I split the text elements out from this HTML String? Python

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

Good Morning,

I'm doing some HTML parsing in Python and I've run across the following which is a time & name pairing in a single table cell. I'm trying to extract each piece of info separately and have tried several different approaches to split the following string.

HTML String:

`<span><strong>13:30</strong><br/>SecondWord</span></a>`

My output would hopefully be:

```
text1 = 13:30
text2 = "SecondWord"
```

I'm currently using a loop through all the rows in the table, where I'm taking the text and splitting it by a new line. I noticed the HTML has a line break character in-between so it renders separately on the web, I was trying to replace this with a new line and run my split on that - however my string.replace() and re.sub() approaches don't seem to be working.
I'd love to know what I'm doing wrong.

Latest Approach:

```
resub_pat = r'<br/>'
rows=list()
for row in table.findAll("tr"):
    a = re.sub(resub_pat,"\n",row.text).split("\n")
```

This is a bit hashed together, but I hope I've captured my problem! I wasn't able to find any similar issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

# the soup
soup = BeautifulSoup("<span><strong>13:30</strong><br/>SecondWord</span></a>", 'lxml')

# the regex object
rx = re.compile(r'(\d+:\d+)(.+)')

# time, text
text = soup.find('span').get_text()
x,y  = rx.findall(text)[0]
print(x)
print(y)
```

Comment: Brilliant, thanks! All of the answers here are excellent but I went with this one as the regex solution is transferable elsewhere too - thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Using `recursive=False` to get only direct text and `strong.text` to get the other one.

**Ex:**

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup("<span><strong>13:30</strong><br/>SecondWord</span></a>", 'lxml')

# text1
print(soup.find("span").strong.text)     # --> 13:30
# text2          
print(soup.find("span").find(text=True, recursive=False))  # --> SecondWord
```

Answer (score 1):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


txt = '''<span><strong>13:30</strong><br/>SecondWord</span></a>'''
soup = BeautifulSoup(txt, 'html.parser')

text1, text2 = soup.span.get_text(strip=True, separator='|').split('|')

print(text1)
print(text2)
```

Prints:

```
13:30
SecondWord
```